# i can't add input tag into td tag when i click td tag (javascript + html)

Tags: javascript, html, events

i have a classic table with tags `table`,`tr`,`th`,`td`, and i want js to add input tag into `td` tag when i click cell (`<td>` tag) in the table.
Here you can see my code, and i can't understand where is mistake:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
//    alert('i am working');
    var input=document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type','text');
    console.log(input);
    document.body.td[i].appendChild(input);
    console.log(td[i]);
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; ...etc` should fix that - or use `this.appendChild(input)` ... i.e. don't use `i` inside the event handler unless it's declared using `let`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `document.body.td[i].appendChild(input);` with `this.appendChild(input);`

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
  td[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    this.appendChild(input);
  })
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>


  <table>
```